# Non-graph way to reason about a polynomial question

Tags: polynomials

### Question

$P(x)$ is a fourth-degree polynomial with real coefficients. Given that,
$$
   \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, P(x) \ge x
$$
and that,
$$
    P(1)=1, P(2)=4, P(3)=3
$$
What is $P(4)$?

### Answer

There is a beautiful solution with the help of the following graph:

[image]

We can reason that $P(x)+x$ must have double roots at $x=1$ and $x=3$, so $P(x)=k(x-1)^2 (x-3)^2 + x$, and we find $k$, etc.

In what other ways one can reason without using a graph?

Comment: I think you mean "We can reason that $P(x) - x$ must have ..."

Comment: The graph isn't actually used for reasoning, more to illustrate the reasoning. I don't think there's going to be a neater way to do it than deducing that $P(x)-x$ is quartic and has two double roots, as this is the most direct use of the given information. (Had you been told, say, that $P$ had integer coefficients, there would be other approaches.)